# Triple integral of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Upon integration,

$\int f(x) \implies $ area of curve.

$\iint f(x) \implies $ volume under the curve.

$\iiint f(x) \implies $ ? . We are expected to come up with something 4 dimensional?

I simply know.

$\iiint 1 \implies $ Volume.

$\iiint \rho(x) \implies $ gives mass.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Yes, it would be the hypervolume of a 4D object. This is a bit tough to imagine, but check out what James Stewart has to say in his Calculus text; in particular, look at his section on "Applications of Triple Integrals" (16.6 p.1031).

Comment: The question is $\int\int\int f(x)=?$
As for James Stewart,
He does not say anything more than what you have already said and what I already wrote. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that a continuous function is integrable over a closed bounded domain. In fact if $f(x,y,z)=1$ on the domain $D$, then you certainly know that the triple integral gives the volume od $D$: $$V=\iiint_D dV$$ Now if $f$ be a positive function, then $$\iiint_D f(x,y,z) dV$$ can be interpreted as the *hypervolume* (i.e. the 4 dimensional volume) of the region in 4-space (which as @B.D noted is a bit hard to imagine)having the set $D$ as its 3-dimentional *base* and having its top on the hypersurface $u=f(x,y,z)$. Of course and indeed, this is not specially useful interpretation but, many more useful cases arise in application which you are aware of them.